# C++ Parallel Asynchonous task

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently building a randomly generated terrain game where terrain is created automatically around the player.  I am experiencing lag when the generated process is active, as I am running quite heavy tasks with post-processing and creating physics bodies.

Then I came to mind using a parallel asynchronous task to do the post-processing for me. But I have no idea how I am going to do that. I have searched for C++ `std::async` but I believe that is not what I want. In the examples I found, a task returned something. I want the task to change objects in the main program.

This is what I want:

```
// Main program

// Chunks that needs to be processed. 
// NOTE! These chunks are already generated, but need post-processing only!
std::vector<Chunk*> unprocessedChunks;
```

And then my task could look something like this, running like a loop constantly checking if there is chunks to process.

```
// Asynced task
if(unprocessedChunks.size() > 0)
{
    processChunk(unprocessedChunks.pop());
}
```

I know it's not far from easy as I wrote it, but it would be a huge help for me if you could push me at the right direction.

In Java, I could type something like this:

```
asynced_task = startAsyncTask(new PostProcessTask());
```

And that task would run until I do this:

```
asynced_task.cancel();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use threads in C++ to do parallel processing? That's what it sounds like.

Comment: Yea, isn't asynced tasks = using threads?

Thanks @ktodisco for editing the post.

Comment: `std::async` will work well for you. It has almost the same syntax as the java example. Canceling can be done with a flag such as an `std::atomic<bool>`. Be aware that only one thread must access a variable at a time, meaning that you cannot pop chunks and push chunks simultaneously, otherwise the code will break horribly.

Comment: Well, this is what I have to do. But I guess I can use std::mutex which I believe can lock/unlock memory access. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [producer-consumer](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming%3amultithreading%3atutorial-06) pattern using threads to do the post-processing work.

Comment: Yea. But in my case, I only need one task; the consumer. The producer is the actual main thread. Do I need to use std::mutex to lock when picking elements? :O